# Let tester directly click on web site to report bugs, similar to bugherd?

Tags: usability-testing, usability, usability-study

I'm doing website User Testing and want them to report issues by clicking on web site and type text into a comment box. Similar to [www.Diigo.com](http://www.diigo.com) or [www.bugherd.com](http://www.bugherd.com)

Bugherd is designed for this but it is still at an early stage -- too unstable for our production use as of Aug 2011. (very impressive though)

Diigo is not designed for bug tracking, it kind of works but I can't really integrate with bug-fixing workflow.

Apart from the obvious screenshot->save image->upload image to a bug tracker, are there easy ways to allow our users to easily point-and-click and input bugs?

Comment: Is there a word or term for this bug tracking method? Smth. like "on page feedback" or similar?

Comment: Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[www.bugmuncher.com](http://www.bugmuncher.com) is the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you need [Google Feedback](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/index.html) ([more here](http://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/learnmore.html)). It's the feedback tool currently integrated into Google+. Once you click it, it pops up a little toolbox that allows you to "highlight the problem" (which uses the DOM to highlight specific HTML elements, rather than asking users to draw on the screen) or "black out personal information" (so you can easily remove private messages etc. without having to use an image tool).

Why it works well:

- **Keep the user in the session**. Rather than creating a barrier to entry involving taking screenshots, saving images and uploading them like you mention, you just click a few times, type a few lines, and forget about it.
- **Offer specific actions rather than asking for images**. Rather than asking for a screenshot or even using any terminology like that, it just talks about *highlighting the problem** and *blacking out personal info*. Then it asks you to add a comment, preview (using a generated screenshot of the page) and send.
- **No tech jargon**. No screenshots, bugtracking, issues, tickets or other typical tech support crap ever comes up. They simplified the process to essentially what you would do if I were sitting next to you: point it out, tell me what the problem is, and we're done. This is very important.

The only problem is that it isn't a product; Google is only using it internally. I'm sure they'll release it into the wild eventually but for now your best bet is to learn from what they're doing and reproduce it the best you can.

Comment: Yes Google+ is where I saw this before! Now I remember. Then some more searches led me to this: http://bugmuncher.com it works like Google Feedback and looks more stable than BugHerd. Will give it a try and it might be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pricing I'd go with http://www.bugherd.com/ which has a free plan and also has Wordpress integration - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bugherd/

Comment: Welcome to User Experience! Thanks for your answer, although can you summarize the content of this link? As [this post on meta stackoverflow discusses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/162091) *"you haven't answered their question, you've deferred the answering to somewhere else."*. If that link were to be taken down, we would lose all context. If you can summarize the article and provide the link as the citation source then you'll be providing a useful answer to the question.